# How to play a wave file Excel/Developer/Visual BASIC?

Tags: excel, vba

The problem has been narrowed down to one line. It is an issue between absolute and relative path.

This line works:
**PlayWavFile "c:\TransmissionFile\AWNP.wav", False**

I prefer something like this but it does not work:
**PlayWavFile "AWNP.wav", False**

I have the wave file in both the C drive and in the same folder as the program. So for the program folder to be portable, I would like to use the relative path. How do I do that? What is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "program"? Workbook?

Comment: Well, I did say Excel, Developer, Visual BASIC now didn't I?  (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question leaves a few open questions. However, taking a best guess approach, I think this is what you're aiming to do:

```
Option Explicit

' assuming this is the Lib declaration:
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, _
ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

' and assuming this is the sub format you're using to call (as declared) sndPlaySound
Sub PlayWavFile(WavFileName As String, Wait As Boolean)
    
    ' Set path based on this workbook's folder location
    Dim stFilePath$: stFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & WavFileName

    ' If file is missing, try root of C drive
    If Dir(stFilePath) = "" Then
        stFilePath = "C:\" & WavFileName
        
        ' Not here either: report and end
        If Dir(stFilePath) = "" Then
            MsgBox WavFileName & " not found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    ' Play the sound (with/without wait)
    If Wait Then
        sndPlaySound stFilePath, 0
    Else
        sndPlaySound stFilePath, 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Mischief Managed.

Comment: Good oh... glad I could help :) Now, could you please mark this as the answer. Let's everyone know the question has been answered.

Comment: When I commented that it worked, I looked for the option to mark as answer the discussion or to give you credit, I did not see it.  I still don't. --- Ok, I think I just found it..... Did it work?

Comment: Yes it did :) Thanks. And that's an interesting comment. Maybe the 'Tick' isn't obvious to others (which would explain the low 'answered' rate when correct answers at given).

Comment: So much is now hidden for some reason.  URLs are no longer identified and you have to guess where links are.  Scrollbars are grey on grey and again, you have to search for the slider. Vital information is small font, grey on slightly lighter gray.  You have to click to find text boxes.  So, yes, the mark-as-answered button is not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim CurrentFolder As String
CurrentFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path
PlayWavFile CurrentFolder & Application.PathSeparator & "AWNP.wav", False
```